# How to fix "Index Out Of Range Exception" when reaching the last index of an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that I'm using to select a random item from an array with a weighted chance and, for the most part, it works well. The problem comes when the index gets to the last item in the array.

Here's my code:

```
string[] grades = { "D", "C", "B", "A", "S" };
int[] weights = { 80, 140, 170, 180, 181 };
// 80, 60, 30, 10, 1

int iterations = 100;

void Update() {
    if (iterations > 0) {
        string genGrade = grades[WeightedChance(weights)];
        print("Chance: " + chance + ", Grade: " + genGrade);
        iterations--;
    }
}

int WeightedChance(int[] weights) {
    float weightSum = weights[weights.Length - 1];

    float chance = Random.Range(0f, weightSum);

    for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length - 1; i++) {
        if (chance <= weights[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

From what I understand when `i` gets to the last item in the array it seems to skip over it and then run `return -1`, giving me "IndexOutOfRangeException". What I can't seem to understand is why exactly that's happening. `chance` generates a number between `0f` and `weightSum` (or `181` in this case), both being inclusive as they're floats. Afterwards I check for each element in `weights` and see if the number generated by `chance` is less than or equal to each one. If all of that runs like I'm thinking it should, it should always be able to choose one of the weights, but something goes wrong when `i` reaches `4` (atleast that's what I'm guessing). I am new to all of this, so I apologize if I'm missing anything important or my code isn't correctly formatted.

Comment: Have you tried a breakpoint to follow the changes? In the left side of VS, you can place a red dot. Then click Attach to Unity then run the game. It will stop at the red dot, you can then use the control at the top to Jump into/skip and so on. Hovering over a variable will show its content.

Comment: @Everts I usually just use a bunch a print functions to see what's happening but that seems like a much better alternative so thanks for that, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not correct:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length - 1; i++) {
```

You should go till "weights.Length" not "weights.Length - 1".

You are not reaching last item.

Comment: Yeah that seemed to be the problem. I'm not entirely sure why though as I thought ```weights.Length - 1``` would be give me ```4```, which would encompass the last element in my array. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: 4 is, of course, the last element in the array but when i is 4, "i < weights.Length - 1" is false, because "4 < 4" is false.. so the for loop is finished and then -1 is returned.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise ```i < weights.Length - 1``` was constantly being checked. I figured that if ```i``` equalled ```3``` it would run through the code, add 1 to ```i``` making it ```4```, run through the code again and only then, before adding to ```i```, see that ```i < weights.Length - 1``` wasn't true. I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @Genzou maybe you were thinking of `i <= weights.Length - 1`. Happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

The error comes on this part:

```
 string genGrade = grades[WeightedChance(weights)];
```

When `WeightedChance` returns -1, you get `grades[-1]`, which of course is out of range

Comment: Yes that was the problem, but I was more asking why I was getting the ```-1``` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
void Update() {
if (iterations > 0) {
  int x= WeightedChance(weights);
   if(x>=0){
    string genGrade = grades[x];
    print("Chance: " + chance + ", Grade: " + genGrade);
    iterations--;
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the `<` operator in your for loop, this means that the value is "strictly less" than what you are comparing meaning that equality does not satisfy this condition.

In your case you are looping to `weights.Length -1` which is, as you say, 4, but the condition in the for loop states that it should run until `i` is "strictly less" than 4 so `i` will reach a maximum value of 3, not checking for the last element `181`.

To solve this issue you have 2 solutions:

- Change the operator to `<=` (less than or equals) which would cover the case of `i=4`
- Run the for loop up to `Weight.Length` without subtractions (as already suggested in other answers)

Comment: My misunderstanding was more about how the for loop was checking the condition. I thought the order was variable > code > condition > increment, rather than the condition always being checked.